# Visual C# - String append to String not working correctly

Tags: c#, string, sockets, append

Good evening,

I have a weird problem. I'm not very familiar with Visual C#, however i need to write a little socket application to enable communication with an iOS application.
Please check below my function that is triggered everytime data is received.

```
public void onDataReceived(IAsyncResult asyn)
    {
        // Debug.WriteLine("Receiving Data");
        try
        {
            CSocketPacket socketId = (CSocketPacket)asyn.AsyncState;
            int iRx = 0;
            iRx = socketId.thisSocket.EndReceive(asyn);
            char[] chars = new char[iRx + 1];
            Decoder d = Encoding.UTF8.GetDecoder();
            int charLen = d.GetChars(socketId.dataBuffer, 0, iRx, chars, 0);
            System.String szData = new System.String(chars);
            Debug.WriteLine(szData);
            stringVar += szData;
            Debug.WriteLine(stringVar);
            szData = "";
            startWaitingForData(socketWorker);
        }
        catch (ObjectDisposedException)
        {
            Debugger.Log(0, "1", "\n onClientConnection: Socket has been closed!\n");
        }
        catch (SocketException error)
        {
            Debugger.Log(0, "1", error.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Sending a message from the iphone to the socket server works great. But there's a problem. If I send a.e. "Message Test" the first Debug.WriteLine(szData) logs the chars correctly. (byte is set to byte[1] so for each byte the function gets called). However if i append the szData to my stringVar property, it won't work correctly. The Debug.WriteLine(stringVar) will always only log the first char, in my example it will log 'MMMMMMMMMMMM' (instead of 'Message Test')

Not sure what I'm missing here. Any help is truly appreciated.

Thank you :)

UPDATE:
Below my startWaitingForData function:

```
public class CSocketPacket
    {
        public System.Net.Sockets.Socket thisSocket;
        public byte[] dataBuffer = new byte[1];
    }

    public void startWaitingForData(System.Net.Sockets.Socket soc)
    {
        // Debug.WriteLine("Start waiting for data");
        try
        {
            if (workerCallBack == null)
            {
                workerCallBack = new AsyncCallback(onDataReceived);
            }
            CSocketPacket socketPacket = new CSocketPacket();
            socketPacket.thisSocket = soc;
            soc.BeginReceive(socketPacket.dataBuffer, 0, socketPacket.dataBuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, workerCallBack, socketPacket);
        }
        catch (SocketException error)
        {
            Debugger.Log(0, "1", error.ToString());
        }
    }
```

For the iphone part, i use ASCII Encoding:

```
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:[message dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
```

The stringVar is defined as:

```
private string stringVar;
```

Comment: Sounds very odd - string concatenation definitely *does* work in .NET, so it's not clear what's wrong. (It would be better to use a `StringBuilder` instead of repeated string concatenation, but that's a different matter.) Can you show a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem? (Also, I'd strongly recommend following the .NET naming conventions.)

Comment: I think we need to see the definition of `stringVar` and that of `startWaitingForData`, since this seems something related to how they are used.

Comment: I did try StringBuilder as well with the same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think more information is needed in order to get to the bottom of this.

However, What encoding is the iPhone sending in?

Also, note that iRx will give you the number of bytes read, but this does not neccessarily equate to the number of Chars read as UTF8 is a multi-byte encoding.

As per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.utf8encoding.getdecoder.aspx) you should use the GetCharCount method to get the number of chars that you need set your array size to.

EDIT: After @Pascal UPDATE

As per Mr Skeet's comment, without a complete version to debug this, it's only guess work as to what the problem is.  Also, your initial description of

> If I send a.e. "Message Test" the first Debug.WriteLine(szData) logs the chars correctly

doesn't seem to ring true if you are sending only one byte at a time?

I would suggest the following as an attempt to fix:

- Increase your buffer size from 1 byte to something more sensible like 256.  Is there any reason you are forcing it to do this 1 byte at a time?
- You have an element of recursion in the fact that your **onDataReceived** handler calls your **startWaitingForData** and this then does BeginRecieve;  Make sure that you are resetting local variables etc. between receives.

Note that your iPhone client should really be using UTF8 if that is the encoding of your server.

Answer (score 0):

Are you always reading only the first Byte of `socketId.dataBuffer`?